# Caching in-app purchase receipt validation certificates on Windows 8

Tags: .net, windows-8, in-app-purchase, certificate, windows-store-apps

I am a bit confused about Microsoft's recommended practices when it comes to validating Windows 8 in-app purchase receipts on a separate server.

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj649137.aspx) documentation page shows the approach when validating the receipts. What I find confusing though is getting and storing the certificate used to validate the receipts. At some point, when retrieving the SSL certificate used in validation, the documentation states the following:

```
// Retrieve the certificate from the official site.
// NOTE: For sake of performance, you would want to cache this certificate locally.
//       Otherwise, every single call will incur the delay of certificate retrieval.
```

This caching suggestion is what confuses me. The certificate is retrieved from a URL built with a parameter that comes from the receipt itself, and which looks something like this:

`https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=246509&cid={0}`,

where `{0}` stands for the certificate ID taken directly from the receipt. But if I should cache it, then any subsequent receipt validation would ignore the certificate id stated in the new receipt. This leads me to think that **all** receipts on Windows 8 must be validated against the same certificate, with the same, never-changing ID (it seems to be `b809e47cd0110a4db043b3f73e83acd917fe1336`). Is this assumption correct? Can I safely cache the certificate after the first request and then ignore all subsequent certificate IDs in receipts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, you have to cache every certificate using its ID as the cache key. Every time you'll face a new certificate ID you must add it to your cache.

For instance, you can build a disk cache. In that case, the certificateId will be used as FileName: 
- Check if a file matching certificate Id exists in your local cache directory
- If it does exists load the certificate from the file on your local disk
- If it does not exists download it, then save it to your local cache directory

Obviously you can do more sophisticated things using AppFabric Caching or Builtin Asp.Net Caching features (or similar technologies).

Comment: Hmm, very valid point, i'm surprised it didn't cross my mind. However, i'd like to use in-memory caching exclusively, but if the number and cummulative size of the certificate is too large this wouldn't be feasible. But how many certificates are there anyway? There can't be that many to be a problem. The real problem is cache invalidation though - how do i know that the certificates haven't changed meanwhile, i.e. if the cached version is the same as the original one, without retrieving the whole certificate? Microsoft doesn't seem to offer a simple way for this. Caching thus seems risky.

Comment: Hard to say if there is many certificates, but Microsoft wouldn't recommand caching if it wasn't feasible.

Comment: Regarding, certificate, it won't change and its the reason they provide this of retrieving the certificate by its ID. So there is no issue with certificate caching. The only thing you might want to do is validate the certificate against CRL (revocation lists) and .net has everything you need to perform that. About in memory caching, you have builtin features with .net 4.0 (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997357.aspx)

Comment: I think i'm going to wait for an official answer from Microsoft regarding these aspects, i've started a thread on their [Windows 8 development forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f1111add-9884-472b-9ee7-e4c39d5cb219/caching-inapp-purchase-receipt-validation-certificates?forum=winappswithcsharp) and i'll get back when i have an answer. Otherwise it's too risky to base IAP receipt validation on speculation.

Comment: Reading your MSDN post, i guess your missing a point about X509 Certificates lifecycle. A certificate issued by an authority is never altered. It might be revoked before its expiration date but the only solution you have to verify that is to check that the certificate is not in the Authority Certificate Revocation List (CRL). Caching won't change anything to that.

Comment: I see, so i don't have to worry about changes to its content, just check each time before i use it that it hasn't expired or hasn't been revoked, the latter of which might incur an online query. If the certificate is not valid anymore, then i simply re-download it given the ID from the MS servers. Sounds about right?

Comment: Yes. In fact if the certificate expired, Microsoft will not use it to sign further Receipt. They will issue a new one with a new id (and you will download this new certificate from MS Servers)

Comment: I just checked the nature of the certificate and it appears to be :
- self signed
- expiration set to 11/11/2036
- no revocation distribution point set (seems logical with a self signed certificate)
My guess is they are pretty confident that their private key won't be disclosed and they won't have to revoke it. 
You can expire you cache after a reasonable time (something between 1 hour and 1 day) to avoid using a deleted certificate. Or you can check it still exists on Microsoft servers asynchronously.

Comment: So, there's no point in validating and checking the certificate against the CRL then? Couldn't this be a potentially serious security breach, especially since the certificate is self-signed?

Comment: Yes :( . There is a security risk but I think Microsoft manage these certificates with same caution as for an Authority Root certificate. The only choice we have is to trust them :(

Comment: Well, since Microsoft doesn't bother giving additional guidance with these certificates, i guess this'll do. Thanks for your patience on this long thread of comments!